# C++11 lvalue-to-rvalue conversion?

Tags: c++, c++11

I think I'm missing something basic regarding the lvalue-to-rvalue standard conversion.

From C++11 4.1:

> A glvalue of a non-function, non-array type T can be converted to a prvalue

So we declare a variable `x`:

```
 int x = 42;
```

An expression `x` in this scope is now an lvalue (so also a glvalue).  It satisfies the requirements in 4.1 for an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.

What is a typical example of a context where the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to the expression `x`?

Answer (score 5):

A prvalue ("pure" rvalue) is an expression that identifies a temporary object (or a subobject thereof) or is a value not associated with any object.

```
struct Bar
{
    int foo()
    {
        int x = 42;
        return x;    // x is converted to prvalue
    }
};
```

the expression `bar.foo()` is a **prvalue**.

OR

Lambda expressions, such as

```
[](int x){return x*x;}
```

§ 3.10.1

A prvalue (“pure” rvalue) is an rvalue that is not an xvalue. [ Example: **The result of calling a function whose return type is not a reference is a prvalue**. The value of a literal such as 12, 7.3e5, or true is also a prvalue. —end example ]

see [n3055](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3055.pdf).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I am saying that "The result of calling a function whose return type is not a reference is a prvalue".

Comment: @billz equivalent (please replace rvalue in my above comment by prvalue. accident). you are not calling a function in your code.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Updated my answer, `bar.foo()` is that what you meant calling a function? I won't say `foo` is prvalue. :)

Comment: I will remove my -1, but want to note that despite a confusing Standard paragraph (which says that rvalues are "temporary objects"), *"A prvalue ("pure" rvalue) is an expression that identifies a temporary object"* is not true. Despite being able to refer to a temporary object by an lvalue indirectly, `const int& a = 10; &a;`, there are non-prvalues that directly refer to them aswell, see 15.1p3 *"Throwing an exception copy-initializes (8.5, 12.8) a temporary object, called the exception object. The temporary is an lvalue and is used to initialize the variable named in the matching handler"*.

Comment: However, that is a very subtle issue and I think your answer is fine as it is. Thanks for fixing it.