# Does lvalue-to-rvalue conversion ever happen to class types?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, lvalue-to-rvalue

Practically every example of lvalue-to-rvalue conversion I've seen on the web relates to fundamental types like `int` etc.

I couldn't find an example of l2r applicable to class types myself; in all the seemingly applicable examples there's usually a function involved that takes lvalue-ref (like copy-ctor), for which l2r seems to be suppressed (see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50024666/lvalue-to-rvalue-conversion-not-performed) question).

However in the description of l2r itself there's a clause about class types (from [conv.lval]):

> the result of the conversion is determined according to the following rules:
>
> <...> if T has a class type, the conversion copy-initializes a temporary of type T from the glvalue and the result of the conversion is a prvalue for the temporary.

Could someone give an example of this clause? I can't.

Comment: There is basic.lval/3 "Note: Whenever a glvalue appears in a context where a prvalue is expected, the glvalue is converted to a prvalue". Something tickles my mind that there are such situations where the standard specifies a prvalue of class type as being expected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example is volatile objects in discarded-value expressions:

```
struct A {};

void f()
{
    volatile A a;
    a;
}
```

According to [[expr.context]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.context#2):

> In some contexts, an expression only appears for its side effects.
>   Such an expression is called a *discarded-value expression*. The
>   array-to-pointer and function-to-pointer standard conversions are not
>   applied. **The lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied if and only if
>   the expression is a glvalue of volatile-qualified type and it is one
>   of the following**:
>
> - ...
> - ***id-expression***,
> - ...

Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to `a`.

Comment: So in that example, is there a copy-initialization of a temporary happening from `a`? Like copy-ctors called etc. I'm mostly interested in copy-initialization part of the clause; or is it elided somehow maybe?..

Comment: @ledonter I think there indeed is.

Comment: Hmm ... doesn't seem to be the case with [GCC and Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/K4jhce).  In fact, Clang says `warning: expression result unused; assign into a variable to force a volatile load [-Wunused-volatile-lvalue]`

Comment: @L.F. There is a [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84699).

Comment: if the Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to `a` then why was not the copy constructor called ? @xskxzr

Comment: @f877576 I think the copy constructor should be called, the bug in the comment above may be related.