# Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion C++

Tags: c++, lvalue-to-rvalue

I read about  [Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Lvalue_to_rvalue_conversion) and  [Comparison operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison)

**This quote from Comparison operators :**

> after the application of the lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer and function-to-pointer standard conversions. The comparison is deprecated if both operands have array type prior to the application of these conversions. (since C++20)

**This quote from Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion :**

> An lvalue (until C++11)A glvalue (since C++11) of any non-function,
> non-array type T can be implicitly converted to an rvalue (until
> C++11)a prvalue (since C++11):
>
> If T is not a class type, the type of the rvalue (until C++11)prvalue
> (since C++11) is the cv-unqualified version of T. Otherwise, the type
> of the rvalue (until C++11)prvalue (since C++11) is T. If an
> lvalue-to-rvalue conversion from an incomplete type is required by a
> program, that program is ill-formed.

I just want to make sure that I understand how this conversion works right ( My Understand ) :

**Example 1 :**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int x=9;
    if(x == 0){
     cout<<"Okay"<<endl;    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Example 2 :**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int x=9;
    if(0 == x){
     cout<<"Okay"<<endl;    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**I concluded two points :**

**The point number 1** : in `Example 1` Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to  the two operands `( x and 0 )` of the `operator ==` before the The comparison
and that is why the `Example 2` is also compiled and run .

**The point number 2** :  Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion  is never applied to class type . ( is that the exact meaning of this section ( because the english is not my native language so I want to make sure that I understand this section totally right ) ? : )

> If T is not a class type, the type of the rvalue (until C++11)prvalue
> (since C++11) is the cv-unqualified version of T. Otherwise, the type
> of the rvalue (until C++11)prvalue (since C++11) is T. If an
> lvalue-to-rvalue conversion from an incomplete type is required by a
> program, that program is ill-formed.

So at the end is my conclusion ( the two points ) totally right ?

**Edit :**
[image]

here the Inside class definition of operators and the Outside class definition
for example for equal to Operator ( == ) the Inside class definition is ( for class T )
`bool T::operator==(const T2& b) const;`
and the Outside class definition is `bool operator==(const T& a, const T2& b);`
So I have four questions for you @Caleth you in your last comment ( under your answer ) " `bool operator==(int &, Foo&)` takes lvalues, whereas `bool operator(int, Bar)` takes rvalues  "

**question number 1 -** what I understand from your comment is `Foo` is a class and `Bar` is also a class is that right ?

you said in another comment `"  for the built-in operators, i.e. both operands are of scalar type, then lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is done because all built-in operators are by-value. For user defined operators, it is or isn't done depending on the declared type of the parameter "`

**question number 2 -**  " the built-in operators, i.e. both operands are of scalar type, then lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is done because all built-in operators are by-value. " I don not understand you said " because all built-in operators are by-value. " when we take a look on the table ( the photo ) we can see that the Outside class definition is `bool operator==(const T& a, const T2& b);`

Is the Outside class definition the definition of built-in operators ?

**question number 3 -** if the answer of the question number 2 is **YES** then why is the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion done when we use built-in operators ( if the parameter in the definition of the built-in operators is not by - value ) and if the answer of the question number 2 is **NO** then What is the difference between Outside class definition and the definition of built-in operators ?

you said " For user defined operators, it is or isn't done depending on the declared type of the parameter " and you explain this by said " `bool operator==(int &, Foo&)` takes lvalues, whereas `bool operator(int, Bar)` takes rvalues  " If we apply your words

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class test {
public:
    test() {
        cout << "test()" << endl;
    }
    test(test&& p) {
        cout << "test( test&& p )" << endl;
    }
    test(const test& p) {
        cout << "test( const test& p )" << endl;
    }
    test& operator==(test p) {
        return p;
    }
};
int main() {
    test p;
    test o;
    p == o;
    return 0;
}
```

**the output of this code is :**

```
test() ------- for test p
test() ------- for test o
test( const test& p ) -------- for operator ==
```

so here the parameter of the overloaded operator `==` is `test p` ( is by - value ) and the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion does not applied

**question number 4 -** does not that make the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion does not applied when you use a class type ( any class type ) with an overloaded operator ( any overloaded operator ) ( even if the parameter of the overloaded operator is by - value or not ) ( there is no case that the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied when you use a class type ( any class type ) with an overloaded operator ( any overloaded operator ) )  ?

you said `"There are user-defined operators that require lvalue-to-rvalue conversions, e.g. bool operator==(int, Bar), and ones that don't, e.g. bool operator==(int &, Foo&)."`

**question number 5 -** you said " `bool operator==(int, Bar)` requires lvalue-to-rvalue conversions "
here `bool operator==(int, Bar)` The lvalue-to-rvalue conversion happens with the parameter `int` and The lvalue-to-rvalue conversion does not happen with the parameter `Bar` , right ?

**sorry for bothering you @Caleth**

Comment: um, you don't have a class type in example two.

Comment: I know example 1 and example 2 does not contain a class type the two examples are for point number 1

Comment: I expect every modern compiler to directly return 0.

Comment: "If T is not a class type ... Otherwise, the type of the rvalue (until C++11)prvalue (since C++11) is T"  It is unclear how you conclude that "Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is never applied to class type"

Comment: @akira hinoshiro if you mean the condition will be false i know that

Comment: @f877576 if the if is false at compile time there is no need to declare int x, so why not just optimize it away and directly return 0?

Comment: @akirahinoshiro the quesiton is not about what the example code returns or how it can be optimized

Comment: Just reading this,  but `test& operator==(test p)` doesn't adhere to the signature of the equality comparison operator as defined in the standard. That might cause UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in Example 1 Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to the two operands ( `x` and `0` )

No. The expression `x` is an lvalue, so it is converted. The expression `0` is already an rvalue, so it is not.

> Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is never applied to class type .

No. There is a sentence starting "Otherwise" after the non-class type case, there is a different rule for class types.

Comment: you said " No. The expression x is an lvalue, so it is converted. The expression 0 is already an rvalue, so it is not. " you means  Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to `x` by " so it is converted " , right  ?

Comment: @f877576 yes, if where it is used needs an rvalue. In the opposite case, you can't get an lvalue out of an rvalue.

Comment: and you said "No. There is a sentence starting "Otherwise" after the non-class type case, there is a different rule for class types." here is the sentence that you mean `Otherwise, the type of the rvalue (until C++11)prvalue (since C++11) is T.` .`T` will be `T` is not that mean no change will happen ( So  Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion  does not applied )  ?

Comment: ???????????????????

Comment: No, type is different to value category. what it means is that in `const std::string str = "blah"; str + str;`, the type is `const string` whereas in `const int i = 1; i + i;` the type is `int`.

Comment: this question is about Comparison operators not any other operator and when did you get const ( in const string ) ? cv-unqualified version of T. Otherwise, the type of the rvalue (until C++11)prvalue (since C++11) is T  ( Otherwise rvalue prvalue is T not cv-unqualified version of T )

Comment: @f877576 `std::string` is a class type, so it's the otherwise part. And it doesn't change for any other operator

Comment: Is the rule of the Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion the non-class type will be changed to rvalue cv-unqualified version of T and the class type will be changed to rvalue of T ( but not cv-unqualified version ) ? ( Is my understanding of the Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion completely correct now ? )  @Caleth

Comment: @f877576 yes, class types keep the cv qualification

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering you.my last question is

Comment: The Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to non class types when I use them with operators ( any operator ) ( only if the non class type is already an lvalue ) on the other hand The Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is not applied to class types when I use them with operators ( any operator ) ( even if the class type is already an lvalue ) ( of course we must overload any operator before we use it with a class type ) ,right ? @Caleth

Comment: And May I ask you to edit this section in your answer "No.The expression x is an lvalue,so it is converted. The expression 0 is already an rvalue, so it is not."to"No.The expression x is an lvalue,so it is converted by The Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.The expression 0 is already an rvalue,so it is not.",please? @Caleth

Comment: @f877576 for the built-in operators, i.e. both operands are of scalar type, then lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is done because all built-in operators are by-value. For user defined operators, it is or isn't done depending on the declared type of the parameter

Comment: Can you explain this "  For user defined operators, it is or isn't done depending on the declared type of the parameter  " ?
@Caleth

Comment: @f877576 `bool operator==(int &, Foo&)` takes lvalues, whereas `bool operator(int, Bar)` takes rvalues

Comment: your last answer made me more confused I edited my question and add 4 question for you and I mentioned your name and I am  sorry for bothering you  @Caleth

Comment: The table in the question is unfortunately not very enlightening when it comes down to language lawyer questions. The actual comparison operators used for scalar types, as in `x == 0` in your example code, are the hypothetical overloads listed far down the page in a paragraph starting with ["In overload resolution against user-defined operators"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison). As you can see, these take the arguments by value and require the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. Therefore, `x` undergoes the conversion, but `0` need not because it is already an rvalue.

Comment: @f877576 that table on cppreference describes user defined operators, and uses const T & because it's a good idea to, not because the language requires it.

Comment: Foo and Bar are some user defined type. They could be pointer-to-class or array-of-class etc

Comment: You Said you said " For user defined operators, it is or isn't done depending on the declared type of the parameter " and you explain this by said " bool operator==(int &, Foo&) takes lvalues, whereas bool operator(int, Bar) takes rvalues " Can you answer the question number 4 ( take the code I edited consederd ) ? @Caleth

Comment: @f877576 There are user-defined operators that require lvalue-to-rvalue conversions, e.g. `bool operator==(int, Bar)`, and ones that don't, e.g. `bool operator==(int &, Foo&)`. In your question 3, the fact that it calls a constructor *at all* indicates that lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is taking place

Comment: I don't understand this section of your comment "In your question 3, the fact that it calls a constructor at all indicates that lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is taking place" ( sorry but english is not my native language )  can you please answer the questions I have edited  ( I edited one more question ( question number 5 ) ) ( you answered the question number one so you can start with question number 2  if you want but if you will start with question number 2 let me know in your comment ) with a very simple english and please explain the section of your comment that I don't understand  @Caleth

Comment: Please answer the questions in order ( I am very sorry for bothering you ) @Caleth

Comment: If the operator accepts paramters by value, whenever you use an lvalue expression, there needs to be lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, which is copy initialising the parameter object from the argument. If you pass an prvalue, it isn't converted, the temporary is materialised into the parameter object

Comment: That isn't different for scalar types using built-in operators, or user-defined types or functions

Comment: does not the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion create a new object ( new temporary object ( rvalue ) ) ( if the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion happens to class type ) ? @Caleth

Comment: @f877576 the purpose of the conversion is to create a new object. That's the same for scalar types, class types and pointer types

Comment: you said "If the operator accepts paramters by value, whenever you use an lvalue expression, there needs to be lvalue-to-rvalue conversion"  and you also said " the purpose of the conversion is to create a new object. That's the same for scalar types, class types and pointer types "  then why the third output of my code ( the code that I edited ) is `test( const test& p )` and it is not  `test( test&& p )` ( does the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion happen in this case ? if your answer is ( yes ) prove it ? ) @Caleth

Comment: Because the copy constructor *is* the lvalue to rvalue conversion. It takes the lvalue and returns an rvalue

Comment: constructor does not return anything @Caleth

Comment: Does the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion happen in this case ( the code that I edited )  ? @Caleth

Comment: @f877576 It is very simple: if you need an rvalue, but provide an lvalue, that value undergoes lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.

Comment: if what you said is a general rule  "  It is very simple: if you need an rvalue, but provide an lvalue, that value undergoes lvalue-to-rvalue conversion " then why if the parameter of the functhion is  a reference to an rvalue ( test && ) and the given parameter is a lvaue the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion does not happen  and an error happens ? @Caleth

Comment: @f877576 Because the rules of the language say that is an error.

Comment: So this sentence "  if you need an rvalue, but provide an lvalue, that value undergoes lvalue-to-rvalue conversion " is not a  general rule , right ? @Caleth

Comment: @f877576 references have rules about what they can bind to. So what I said was only complete in the context of values, not references

Comment: so " the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion never happens to the class type with the same way that the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion happens to the non class type ( the copy constructor always is called when ever the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion happens to the class type ) " is that sentence is totally correct ? @Caleth

Comment: @f877576 only in the sense that scalar types don't have constructors

Comment: English is not my native language . does "only in the sense" mean : my comment is correct **because** scalar types don't have constructors or it means my comment is correct **only in the case** the scalar types don't have constructors **and** is there a case that the scalar types have constructors ? @Caleth

Comment: @f877576 because they don't have constructors

Comment: in the answer of this question ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60984469/does-lvalue-to-rvalue-conversion-ever-happen-to-class-types ) there is a snippet of code ( the writer of that answer said the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion happens ) but when i try to compile and run that code the copy constructor is not called @Caleth

Comment: @f877576 copies can be elided beyond the "as-if" rule

Comment: Can you answer my last question  ( my last comment  ) with an easy English language ? ( I don't understand your last comment does it make the answer of my question  yes or no ?  I am Sorry but English is not my native language ) @Caleth

Comment: @f877576 how are you determining the copy constructor isn't called? In the code you showed, there's no observable difference

Comment: if you mean the code in the answer of this question ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60984469/does-lvalue-to-rvalue-conversion-ever-happen-to-class-types ) .yes the copy constructor isn't called but when i asked the author of that answer he said " I think the copy constructor should be called, the bug in the comment above may be related. "  @Caleth

Comment: @f877576 Oh, it's simpler then. The compiler in question is wrong to not call the copy constructor in that situation

Comment: @f877576 There are situations where compilers are allowed to omit copies, by having two values be the same object

Comment: you said in a previous comment " the fact that it calls a constructor at all indicates that lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is taking place " does " at all " mean ( the move constructor ( not only the copy constructor ) can be called to indicate that lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is taking place ) ? @Caleth

Comment: @f877576 only a copy constructor

Comment: i try to write a comment but it is too long so i link this comment as a photo. please answer this comment (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RoQL.png) @Caleth

Comment: @f877576 both of those are talking about providing rvalues. There is no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion in those cases, because you don't have an lvalue to convert. The name "lvalue-to-rvalue conversion" should really be "glvalue-to-prvalue conversion" if you want to match the value categories post C++11

Comment: So the answer of my question ( my comment ) that is in this photo (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RoQL.png) is " yes " ,right @Caleth

Comment: @f877576 when I said "require", that was specifically in the context of passing lvalues. You can't do lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to an rvalue

Comment: I do not understand this sentence ( because english is not my native language ) : " if you want to match the value categories post C++11 " Can you rewrite this sentence in a different format , please ? and thank you for answering my questions patiently @Caleth

Comment: @f877576 The term "lvalue-to-rvalue" conversion was coined before additional value categories were introduced in C++11. The names of the value categories that actually correspond is glvalue and prvalue now.

Comment: what i understand from your last comment is  "  The term "lvalue-to-rvalue conversion " was coined before additional value categories were introduced in C++11. and because c++11 added new value categories then the name "lvalue-to-rvalue conversion " changed into "glvalue-to-prvalue conversion" "is that what you totally meant ( or there is a something i missed ) ? @Caleth

Comment: I mean the term stayed the same, but the meaning of "lvalue" and "rvalue" changed. "glvalue" and "prvalue" have the old meaning in this case

Comment: so just the name of the conversion changed post c++11 (  from "lvalue-to-rvalue conversion " to "glvalue-to-prvalue conversion" ) to include the new value categories  . but what the conversion does did not change . this is what you exactly mean , right? @Caleth

Comment: @f877576 the name *didn't* change, so if you took the name literally, you might get confused

Comment: okay . but what the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion does ( before C++11 ) is exactly the same as what the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion does ( post C++11 ) , right ? @Caleth

Comment: @f877576 yes, nothing changed